# ajax jquery and drupal not work, please see why

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal

drupal 6: here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/GGVFfAGS

```
//getcity.js:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#edit-field-house-geo-area-value").bind('change', function(){

        selected_loc=$("#edit-field-house-geo-area-value option:selected").val();
        var myURL="http://whatever.com/getajax/citys/"+selected_loc+"/";
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: myURL,
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
             }
            });

    });
});
```

drupal module:

```
function sf_menu()
{
  cache_clear_all();
  $items = array ();
  $items ['getajax/citys/%'] = array ('title' => 'This is my custom page', 'page callback' => 'sf_get_cities_ajax', 'access arguments' => array ('access content' ), 'access callback' => 'user_access', // TRUE will give access to everyone
'page arguments' => array (2 ), 'type' => MENU_CALLBACK );
  return $items;
}  

function sf_get_cities_ajax($cityid)
{
  $termsarray = array ();
  $terms = array ();
  $cityid_safe = (int)$cityid;
  $cityid_safe = check_plain($cityid_safe);
  if (is_number($cityid_safe)) {
    $terms = taxonomy_get_children($cityid_safe, 143, 'tid');
    if (count($terms)) {
      foreach ($termsarray as $k => $v) {
        $termsarray [check_plain($k)] = t($v [tid]);
      }
     $f= array('status' => 1, 'data' => $termsarray,'moo'=>'sadasdsd');
    print drupal_json($f);

    exit();
    }

  }
}
```

its not return me somthing even i print the 'moo' data

---

its my function its working fine i get array at the final but its dont pass it

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it should work except one thing... PHP doesn't have a function 'is_number()' so unless you wrote your own you need to change your IF statement to use PHP built in 'is_numeric':

```
if (is_numeric($cityid_safe)) {
```

Its not a JS issue at all.